# VueJS/Nuxt/Vuex: How to insert content into template from state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, wordpress-rest-api, nuxt.js

I'm new to VueJS and am attempting to build an app that pulls in content from a WordPress instance using VueJS, Nuxt and Vuex and the WordPress REST API. I am able to connect to the API, and I have the content being pulled in via state, but I am unable to figure out how to get that data from state and into the template. Everything I try results in "x is not a function" or "x is not defined" errors.

I've looked at various blog posts online but can't find a solution that works. Where am I going wrong?

**store/index.js**

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";

const createStore = () => {
    return new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            explore: null,
            pages: null
        },
        actions: {
            getExplore: function(context) {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    if (context.state.explore) {
                        resolve()
                    }
                    else {
                        axios.get(path_to_api_endpoint)
                        .then((response) => {
                            context.commit('storeExplore', response.data)
                            resolve()
                        }).catch((error) => {
                            reject(error);
                        });
                    }
                })
            },
            getSinglePage: function() {
                return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    this.$store.dispatch('getExplore')
                    .then(() => {
                        var foundPage = false;
                        this.$store.state.pages
                        .filter((page) => {
                            if(pageName === this.$route.params.slug) {
                                this.singlePage = page;
                                foundPage = true;
                            }
                        });
                        foundPage ? resolve() : reject();
                    })
                })
            }
        },
        mutations: {
            storeExplore(state, response) {
                state.explore = response
            },
            storePages(state, response) {
                state.pages = response }
            }
    })
}

export default createStore
```

**pages/explore/_slug/index.vue (Parent Component)**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <layout-browserupgrade></layout-browserupgrade>
        <div class="wrapper" :toggle-nav="showHideNav" :class="navState">
            <layout-toolbar @showHideNav="showHideNav"></layout-toolbar>
            <layout-hero :pageRef="pageId"></layout-hero>
            <explore-detail></explore-detail>
            <layout-footer></layout-footer>
        </div>
        <layout-nav></layout-nav>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    import layoutBrowserupgrade from '~/components/layout/browserupgrade.vue'
    import layoutToolbar from '~/components/layout/toolbar.vue'
    import layoutHero from '~/components/layout/heroStatic.vue'
    import layoutFooter from '~/components/layout/footer.vue'
    import layoutNav from '~/components/layout/nav.vue'
    import exploreDetail from '~/components/pages/detail.vue'

    const axios = require('axios');

    export default {
        components: {
            layoutBrowserupgrade,
            layoutToolbar,
            layoutHero,
            layoutFooter,
            layoutNav,
            exploreDetail
        },
        created: function() {
            this.$store.dispatch('getExplore')
        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                navState: 'menu-closed',
                feedLoaded: false,
                pageDetails: [],
                pageId: null,
                pageType: 'single',
                pageName: this.$nuxt.$route.params.slug
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {
            this.pageId = this.$nuxt.$route.params.pageId;
        },
        watch: {
            feedLoaded: function() {

                if (this.feedLoaded == true) {
                    this.pageId = this.pageDetails.id;
                } else {
                    console.log('Feed did not load')
                }

            }
        },
        methods: {
            showHideNav: function(event) {
                if (this.navState == 'menu-closed') {
                    this.navState = 'menu-open'
                } else {
                    this.navState = 'menu-closed'
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**pages/detail.vue (Page Detail component - Single Page)**

```
<template>
    <main class="main detail-page">
        <div>
            <h1>Explore {{ title.rendered }}</h1>
            <div class="detail-wrapper">
                <section class="detail-intro detail-content-block"></section>
                <section class="detail-map">
                    <p>Map</p>
                </section>
            </div>
            <section class="detail-history">
                <h1>History</h1>
                <div class="detail-content-block"></div>
            </section>
            <section  class="detail-wildlife">
                <h1>Wildlife and Flora</h1>
                <div class="detail-content-block"></div>
            </section>
            <section class="detail-places">
                <h1>Places to See</h1>

            </section>
            <section class="detail-facilities">
                <h1>Accommodation and Facilities</h1>
                <div class="detail-content-block"></div>
            </section>
            <section class="detail-gettingthere">
                <h1>Getting to </h1>
                <div class="detail-content-block"></div>
            </section>
        </div>
    </main>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        created: function() {

        },
        data: function() {
            return {
                pageName: this.$nuxt.$route.params.slug,
                pageRef: null,
                pageContent: null,
                pageType: 'single'
            }
        },
        computed: {
            exploreContent: function() {
                return this.$store.state.explore
            },
            getSinglePage: function() {
                return this.$store.state.pages
            }
        },
        mounted: function() {

        },
        methods: {

        }
    }
</script>

<style lang="scss">

    .detail-page {

        h1 {
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            display: block;
            background-color: $crimson;
            color: #fff;
            text-align: center;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 20px;
            font-family: $font-title;
            font-size: 28px;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        p {
            font-family: $font-default;
            font-size: 1rem;
            font-weight: 400;
            line-height: 1.5;
        }

    }

    .detail-wrapper {
        display: grid;
    }

    .detail-intro {
        grid-column-start: 1;
        grid-column-end: 4;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 2;
    }

    .detail-map {
        grid-column-start: 4;
        grid-column-end: 6;
        grid-row-start: 1;
        grid-row-end: 2;

        min-width: 40vw;
        min-height: 100%;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        text-align: center;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;

        p {
            align-self: center;
            justify-self: center;
        }
    }

    .detail-content-block {
        padding: 40px;
    }

</style>
```

I've removed all the interpolation of the data for testing, just to see if I can get one part to work.

Can anyone point to some docs that can help me, or show me where I'm going wrong? I think I've got the store part right, it's the rest that's letting me down.

Apprecaite any help that can be offered as I'm running out of time to figure it out.

Thanks!

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your pages use `asyncData`, this is a method **only** within **pages** that is called every time before loading the page component.

install axios `npm i axios`. A library to handle ajax request based on promise.

and in pages/detail.vue

```
<script>
  import axios from 'axios'
  ...

  asyncData({ params }) {
    return axios
      .get(
        APIENDPOINT
      )
      .then(data => {
        return {
          data
        };
      })
      .catch(e => context.error());
  },

  ...
</script>
```

For a deep insight check the documentation 
https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data

Comment: Thank you! I'm already using Axios for other parts of the app. If I'm not using state, how will the component know which page data to get from the API dynamically?

Actually I think I found the answer to that question in the docs you linked!

Comment: Glad could i help.

Comment: I've read the docs and tried to set it up, but when I load the template it tells me `[Vue warn]: Property or method "title" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by initializing the property.` - Am I missing something?